# Does document function always reads the input file everytime during transformation?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my question about document function.

Does the document function always reads the input file for each transformation ? or Does it load it into memory for first time and later read from memory for successive transformation ?

The reason to ask this question here is, I have a very input file that always checks values during transformation.

How to achieve the best performance for these situations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification of the `document` function in XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#document) delegates the details of parsing the XML from a single URL to [the specification of the XSLT/XPath/XQuery `doc` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc). It does not specify whether a parsed document is cached but it requires the function to be **stable**, saying "By default, this function is ·stable·. Two calls on this function return the same document node if the same URI Reference (after resolution to an absolute URI Reference) is supplied to both calls. Thus, the following expression (if it does not raise an error) will always be true: doc("foo.xml") is doc("foo.xml")".

It is likely that an implementation caches the result to achieve that which can be an advantage if you want to access the same document multiple times but can be a disadvantage if you load several large documents and have no means disposing any of them.

Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? Saxon has http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/discard-document to explicitly discard a cached document so that suggests that a call to `document('foo.xml')` or `doc('foo.xml')` is normally cached.

Comment: Yes, Saxon 6.5.5 for XSLT 1.0

Comment: My comment refers to Saxon 9.5 and XSLT 2.0 as you tagged the question as `xslt-2.0`.

Comment: Any idea for xslt 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Documents read using doc() or document() will almost inevitably be cached for the duration of a transformation, because that is the only way of satisfying the stability requirements in the spec. But I think your question is about caching across multiple transformations. That's going to be processor dependent.

There's very little reason to be using Saxon 6.5 these days. Even if you want to restrict yourself to XSLT 1.0 for portability reasons, it's usually better to use a more recent Saxon release.

Saxon (at least current releases, I don't recall for 6.5) will cache documents for the lifetime of a JAXP Transformer, so if you use the same Transformer for multiple transformations, the document will not be re-parsed. For more precise control, consider using the s9api API. This allows you to use a DocumentBuilder to build the document tree in memory, and then pass it to each transformation either as the value of a stylesheet parameter, or in response to calls on doc() or document() by registering a URIResolver that recognizes the URI. Also of course - with any JAXP transformation engine - you can implement your own document cache within the URIResolver.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `document()` function, the library has no way of
knowing whether you will use it again, or whether this is a
transient access.
Any time you work with a document, it has to be
parsed, etc., which is relatively time-consuming.  In order to avoid
the overhead of re-reading and re-parsing a document multiple times,
the library maintains a "document list" as a part of the
"transformation context".  The parsed image of any document which is
accessed is added to this list, and the list (together with the
documents it references) is only freed when the transformation
context is freed.

Comment: For example, if the transformation is called 100 time, then first call to the document function reads the file and loads them into memory as parsed image/object. From second call, whenever the document function is called, it only refers to object and no more calls to the file reading. Is this what you were saying ? Sorry, I am still in confusion. If you have examples or links to explain more, please help.